# Entity Framework setting Auto DateTime Column to: 01/01/0001 00:00:00

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2005

I have a MS SQL Srver 2005 Database, that has a table with a DatTime column. The DateTime column is of **smalldatetime** type. The date and time is auto generated by the DB using **getdate()** function. This is because its a LOG recording table, so logs are just inserted and date-time is generated by the db.

When creating a log and saving into the DB through Entity Framework, using LINQ query, it causes an error while saving saying:

**"SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."**

upon investigating using breakpoints i have noticed, when Entity Framework tries to save the Log object, the date set by Entity Framework is set to:

**01/01/0001 00:00:00**

I guess this is why error is coming up. Is there any way to resolve this?

I am using .Net 3.5 framework.

Regards.

Comment: sorry, its getdate() // not getgate()

Comment: You can edit your question you know - the link is just below the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EDMX change StoreGeneratedPattern for your date property to Computed. Be awere that there was a [bug](http://geeksharp.com/2010/05/27/ef4-bug-in-storegeneratedpattern-ssdl/) (not sure if the bug is already fixed) where changing this property in designer affected only CSDL part of EDMX file. You also need to add it to SSDL part.

Comment: Thankyou ... i just changed the SSDL. (i was trying in CSDL, but it said propert not allowed ... or some thing similar. so i just changed in the SSDL part.) Thanks alot ...